# Appending Values Consistently in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, append

EDIT: Just changing the code to show my attempt at the Singleton suggestion.

So I am attempting to create an application which would take the selection of a user from a UITableView and pass that to another UITableView. Then, it would be appended to the array in that view and presented as the new table. The idea being that users can select from multiple lists and create one list made of all their selections.

However, I am extremely new to iOS development and while I can get it to let me take the selected value and show it in the new UITableView, it only sends the one value and does not keep or append it. Meaning I can never show multiple additions to the list.

So, what I'm getting atm is the ability to select a cell, let's say "Kevin Smith", and that value gets sent to the new UITableView and shown to the user. But if I go and select another value, "John Smith", then only John shows up and Kevin is gone.

Here is my three controllers involved:

The first UITAbleView Controller

```
    class PlayerViewController: UITableViewController {

var resultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Player>!
let CDSPlayer = coreDataStackPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Player> = Player.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "level", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: request,
        managedObjectContext: CDSPlayer.managedContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil
    )

    resultsController.delegate = self

    do{
        try resultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Perform Fetch Error: \(error)")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return resultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ _tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath)
    let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    let player = resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = player.name

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "player2form", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style:.destructive, title: "Delete"){(action, view, completion) in
        let player = self.resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        self.resultsController.managedObjectContext.delete(player)
        do {
            try self.resultsController.managedObjectContext.save()
            self.errorMessage(message: "Player Character Deleted.");
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            print("Delete Failed: \(error)")
            self.errorMessage(message: "Failed to Delete Player Character.");
            completion(false)
        }
    }
    action.image = UIImage(named: "trash")
    action.backgroundColor = .red
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
}

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

    if let _ = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, let vc = segue.destination as? AddPlayerViewController{
        vc.managedContext = resultsController.managedObjectContext
    }

    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, let vc = segue.destination as? AddPlayerViewController{
        vc.managedContext = resultsController.managedObjectContext
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell){
            let player = resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            Service.shared.allPlayers.append(player) 
            vc.player = player
        }
    }
}

//Error Function
func errorMessage(message:String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil);

    alert.addAction(okAction);
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil);
}
}

extension PlayerViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type{
    case .insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
            let player = resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = player.name
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The Selection view that passes the data:

```
    class AddPlayerViewController: UIViewController {

var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var player: Player?
var selectedItems = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var done_btn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var playerInput: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var cancel_btn: UIButton!

@IBAction func add2combat(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "player2combat", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func done(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let name = playerInput.text, !name.isEmpty else {
        return //Add notice user cannot save empty items
    }

    if let player = self.player {
        player.name = name
    } else {
        //Set values from input to the cell
        let player = Player(context: managedContext)
        player.name = name
    }

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        playerInput.resignFirstResponder()
        dismiss(animated: true)
    } catch {
        print("Error Saving Player Character: \(error)")
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "player2combat" {
        let selectedItems : [String] = [playerInput.text!]
        let otherVc = segue.destination as! CombatSceneViewController
        otherVc.selectedItems = selectedItems
        print(selectedItems)
    }
}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playerInput.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playerInput.becomeFirstResponder()

    if let player = player {
        playerInput.text = player.name
        playerInput.text = player.name
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

And the UITableView that gets the data and tries to append it to the existing Array.

```
    class CombatSceneViewController: UITableViewController{

var selectedItems =  Service.shared.allSelectedItems

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let otherVC = AddPlayerViewController()
    selectedItems.append(contentsOf: otherVC.selectedItems)

    saveData()
    loadData()
    print(selectedItems)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return selectedItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ _tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CombatCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItems[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func saveData() {
    let data = NSMutableData()

    // 1
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let path = paths[0]
    let file = (path as NSString).appendingPathComponent("Persistent.plist")

    //2
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
    archiver.encode(selectedItems, forKey: "Agents")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.write(toFile: file, atomically: true)
}

func loadData() {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let path = paths[0]
    let file = (path as NSString).appendingPathComponent("Persistent.plist")

    // 1
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: file) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: file) {
            let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data as Data)
            selectedItems = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "Agents") as! [String]

            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }
    }
}
```

Singleton Class:

```
    class Service {

static let shared = Service()

var allPlayers = [Player]()

var allSelectedItems = [String]()
}
```

I hope I did the formatting right... this is my first post on here, be gentle^^;.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you go back the old player is gone because you don't keep it , you can try to create a singleton for that

```
class Service {

   static let shared = Service()

   var allPlayers = [Player]()

   var allSelectedItems = [String]()

}
```

// keep it here

```
  if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, let vc = segue.destination as? AddPlayerViewController{
    vc.managedContext = resultsController.managedObjectContext
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell){
        let player = resultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        Service.shared.allPlayers.append(player)  // add this line
        vc.player = player
    }

 }
```

Do same logic to append selected items and when you reach final tableView access them with

```
Service.shared.allPlayers
```

Or

```
Service.shared.selectedItems
```

That way you have a persisted container for all the selected players & items accessible anyWhere inside the app

Comment: I implimented what you suggested, keeping in mind my nubile nature to iOS, and it still does the same thing it was doing before. I cannot directly append the Service.shared.allSelectedItems OR the Service.shared.allPlayers because my container is an array of strings but allSelectedItems is also an array of strings and it wants it to be of type String? Meanwhile, allPlayers if of type Player and so it wont go in either. I also tried just putting in Service.shared.selectedItems like you suggested but there is no variable by that name in Service - only in the UITableView.

Comment: I did get the Singleton working and recognized, however it still only appends 1 value to the array (now as two of the same element on the list weirdly. Maybe my appending logic is screwy?

Comment: @DemicaFatali check
 whether the array contains the item before the insertion

Comment: I have a print command testing that. It gets the 1 element every time but never adds it to an existing list it seems. It just keeps presenting me the 1 name I selected at the time... should I update my post here with the new code?